# About the bear-headed goddess

Tags: identification-request, goddess

I have recently saw the bear-headed goddess. The picture is shown in below:
[image]

Who is this goddess? Is any scriptures mention her?

Comment: I am assuming the image is not referring to Jāmbavatī, daughter of Jāmbavan.

Comment: There's a Devī named Ṛkṣakarṇī, who is one of the aṣṭaśaktis sthita within Brahmāṇī, as stated in Agni Purāṇa (146.19). But I am not sure, if she has a Ṛkṣamukha (bear face) too, apart from having Ṛkṣakarṇa (bear-ears). Afaik, she doesn't have a Ṛkṣamukha, but her vāhana is a ṛkṣa, and she has ṛkṣakarṇa

Comment: This is not an authentic presentation of any Devī at all. Even the bear's face painted/drawn is that of a teddy bear. And the hands and upper body is like a bear, which is not the case for any Devī.

Comment: This looks like one of those AI generated pics which do not follow any Shastriya depiction of any god or goddess