# Info about Goddess Rikshakarni

Tags: identification-request, goddess

In the comment of [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58345/about-the-bear-headed-goddess), i have heard that there was a goddess called Rikshakarni, who was one of Astha Sakthis. I want to know more about this goddess,

So my question is, is there any other info (story or hymns) about this goddess?

Answer (score 2):

There are 8 śaktis (called aṣṭaka), which are sthita in Brahmāṇī - Akṣodyā, **Ṛkṣakarṇī**, Rākṣasī, Kṣapaṇā, Kṣayā, Piṅgākṣī, Akṣayā, & Kṣemā, as stated in Agni Purāṇa ([146.19](https://archive.org/details/cntJ_agni-puran-first-part-with-hindi-translation-by-tarinish-jha-hindi-sahitya-sammelan-prayag/page/n805/mode/2up?view=theater))

> akṣodyā hyṛkṣakarṇī ca rākṣasī kṣapaṇakṣayā / 
> piṅgākṣī cākṣayā kṣemā brahmāṇyaṣṭakasaṃsthitāḥ //

In [Vratakhaṇḍa (1) of Caturvargacintācintāmaṇi](https://archive.org/details/ChaturvargaChintamaniOfHemadriVol2ByPtBharataChandraShiromaniChaukhambaSanskritSansthan/page/n127/mode/2up?view=theater), Hemādri mentions the svarūpa of Ṛkṣakarṇī

> ṛkṣakarṇī tu gaurāṅgo kamvutrāṇābhayāvahā / 
> dhanuḥ kapālabhṛtasaumye ṛkṣasthā tarjjanosthitā //

Ṛkṣakarṇī is in [Guhyakālyāḥ sahasranāmastotram of Mahākāla saṁhitā (Guhyakāli khaṇḍa)](https://archive.org/details/mahakalasamhitaguhyakalikhandakishornathjhapart2rashitriyasanskritsanstha_202003_632_X/page/n235/mode/2up?view=theater)

> svarakarṇī ṛkṣakarṇī sūrpakarṇā balābalā / 
> mahānīleśvarī jātavetasī kokatuṇḍikā // (10.1979)

Apart from these sources, I am not aware of other mentions regarding her, as of now.
This Devī is very less known and many may not have even heard her name.

Comment: Hello Bingming, I saw you were discussing that there were alternations in Bhavisya Purana by Christian missionaries. Can you please write an answer for that here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/57550/influence-of-abrahamism-in-hinduism-through-puranas, given if you have reliable sources about alterations in the texts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not really interested in this topic now. Sorry. But this would be related to what I was addressing https://www.stephen-knapp.com/jesus_predicted_in_the_vedic_literature.htm
https://grahamhancock.com/phorum/read.php?1,138929,138929 
@User29449

Comment: Okay, I'll check them.

Comment: @User29449 second link is not from a reliable source, but the content shared is from the Purāṇa. It presents the Adam-Eve incident, which is messed up, it shouldn't appear in a Hindu śāstra.

Comment: I've been to Puri, I came to know the manuscripts of Bhavisya Purana that is in puri (original one) is only 2% revealed to the public and is far different from other manuscripts in the country. It is kept in secrecy.

Comment: @User29449 That's nice, such manuscripts are unfortunately unpublished, and so most people don't have access to them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151732/discussion-between-bingming-and-user-29449).